# Generate polygon shaped as a circle if projected using Web Mercator, in Python?

Tags: python, circle, web-mercator

I need to solve problem very similar to [Generating polygon representing rough 100km circle around latitude/longitude point using Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268250/generating-polygon-representing-rough-100km-circle-around-latitude-longitude-poi) but subtly different.

I need a shape that will be a circle once projected in Web Mercator - not in reality.

Working answer ( https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268251/45061 ) is not generalizable, as it relies on https://github.com/jwass/geog that will not allow doing what I am trying to do.

Comment: A geometric object which is a circle when presented in Web Mercator is of very limited use ("How not to generate geometries" seminar is all I can think of).  The easiest way to generate is a simple buffer in Web Mercator, then deproject.  But first you need to select a GIS software stack.

Comment: @Vince I know that it is fairly unusual. If anyone worries about using it for anything serious, it is for generating boundaries of laser-cut decoration plates on scales small enough that usual Web Mercator deficiencies are not relevant (city centers - so remembering to keep the same scale should be sufficient). Also, as it is for decorations most of Web Mercator issues are not really relevant.

Comment: Web Mercator's deficiencies as a map projection are so numerous that I consider paper with ink jet ink an unconscionable waste of materials in map production. I can't imagine using any more exotic material being used. If the print cost is measured in dollars, a local Albers Equal Area or Lambert Conformal would be a more worthy projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite it being an abomination in so many ways, *Pseudo/Spherical (Web) Mercator* is a **projection** after all, so basic math on the Cartesian plane applies:

```
import math

R = 6378137.0


def LL2SM(ll):
  return [math.radians(ll[0]) * R, math.log(math.tan(math.pi / 4 + math.radians(ll[1]) / 2)) * R]

def SM2LL(xy):
  return [math.degrees(xy[0] / R), math.degrees(2 * math.atan(math.exp(xy[1] / R)) - math.pi / 2.0)]

def VERTEX(cxy, a, r):
  return [cxy[0] + r * math.cos(math.radians(a)), cxy[1] + r * math.sin(math.radians(a))]


def main():
  vertices = 32

  center = [13.0, 52.0]
  radius = 100000

  circle = []

  _angle = 360.0/vertices
  for vertex in range(0, vertices):
    sm = LL2SM(center)
    cv = VERTEX(sm, vertex*_angle, radius)
    ll = SM2LL(cv)

    circle.append(ll)

  # do sth. with your circle
  print(circle)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This POC script

1. transforms a pair of Longitude/Latitude (`center`) into EPSG:3857 coordinates (`LL2SM()`)
2. generates `vertices` amount of points on a circle with a given `radius` (in *meter*) around `center`, using its [parametric equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations) (`VERTEX()`)
3. transforms each vertex' coordinates back to Longitude/Latitude (`SM2LL()`)

`circle` will then hold coordinate arrays (`[Longitude, Latitude]`) which, when transformed again to EPSG:3857, will form a circle around `center`.

Obviously, you can skip transforming back to Longitude/Latitude if you want.

---

You haven't specified any software environment other than *Python*, so I leave translating this into the framework of your choice to you; this includes generating an actual *Polygon*, for which there likely are built-in functions.

**Edit:**

```
...
# do sth. with your circle
wkt_polygon = ''.join(['POLYGON((', ','.join([' '.join(map(str, ll)) for ll in circle + [circle[0]]]), '))'])

print(wkt_polygon)
```

will output a *Polygon* as valid *Well Known Text* representation.

Comment: Note that this is obviously the basic and manual math version of the general workflow (*project center -> create buffer -> deproject buffer*), which should be covered in all spatial frameworks. Good to know the math, though. Keep it simple once in a while.